# Can't connect ROS with FANUC ROBOGUIDE

Tags: ros, fanuc

I'm trying to connect an LR Mate 200iC robot with ROS, I already configured the controller with the ROS files, as explained in the tutorials. But when running the program

```
roslaunch fanuc_lrmate200ic_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch \
    robot_ip:=192.168.0.106 use_bswap:=false
```

the following error appears

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Two things: 1.
It is better to paste the text from the error rather than a screenshot. Images are not text-searchable. 2. Please add the hyperlink to tutorials you followed. Thank you for your kind cooperation.